# how do i open a new window with a new buffer, containing a variable?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to write a plugin:

I have a variable with some text.
I want to:

1. create a new buffer
2. place the contents of that variable in the new buffer
3. open a new split that displays the new buffer
4. keep focus on the current window (not the new one)

I'm having a *really* hard time googling for 2 and 3 and I'm not 100% sure I'm doing 1 correctly either. I'm assuming 4 isn't hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for `register`, `String`, and `List`:

```
" don't use <q-args> here, we need expression
com -nargs=1 ShowVariable call s:show_var(<args>)

function s:show_var(var) abort

  " split new buffer
  new

  " set buffer content
  if type(a:var) == v:t_string

    " split string into list, otherwise you see ^@ as newline
    call setline(1, split(a:var, "\n"))
  else
    call setline(1, a:var)
  endif

  " go back to original window
  wincmd p
endfunction
```

[:h setline()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29)
[:h :wincmd](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd)

---

examples:

```
:ShowVariable @@
:ShowVariable string_variable_name
:ShowVariable list_variable_name
```

Comment: thanks for an answer that goes above and beyond. :)